# What does & stands for in C and mmap()

Tags: c, mmap

```
int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
present = (unsigned char *)mmap(0, 
              getpagesize(), 
              PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
              MAP_SHARED, 
              fd, 
              0x22400000);

if ((*present & 1) == 0)
{
  printf("Converter not present\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

1) What does '&' operator mean in the preceding code?

Comment: -1 For lack of research effort

Comment: For future reference: next time you ask a question, make sure you show that you have done a research effort, and not simply dumping a question on SO. You'll quite certainly avoid the downvotes and attract more positive help.

Answer (score 4):

It is the [bitwise and operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0zec0b2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This means that the result of the operation is to perform binary `and` of the two operands but bit-by-bit (in a bitwise fashion i.e).

In this case it is checking that the first bit of the memory pointed to by present is 0.